# Css rtl overflow turns into dots (...) what is the solution?

Tags: css, overflow, right-to-left

My Arabic text turns into dots

ex: لعبة سوبر ماريو
Became: لعب....

I have tried to add Direction:rtl;
and Text-overflow:clip;
But the issue remains this is the current css settings

[class*="gmcn-smal"] .gm-titl{line-height: 20px;font-weight: 700;font-size: 12px;}

By the way it's working fine with English characters

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
#s2 { color: red; }

div
{
   direction: rtl;
}

span
{

}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/22Qk9/21/)**